# How to set a "plain" or "flat" background color for a QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a QTableWidget. I want to have alternating background colors for the rows, but I can't use QTableWidget::setAlternatingRowColors because I need one color for two rows and the other one for the next two and so on (see the below image).

Thus, when I add a QTableWidgetItem, I set the according background color manually by QTableWidgetItem::setBackground().

But I don't get a "flat" or "plain" background by this, but a gradient and rounded corners:

[image: Cell color]

I would like to have the background color all over the cells, without further "decoration". How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Not sure if this works but I have the following idea: Since `setBackground` accepts a `QBrush`, and since `QBrush` can be constructed from an image, you could try to use a 1-pixel image as the background. I think it is then simply repeated over the area.

Comment: I already tried to set a QBrush. Didn't work ...

Comment: What was the result? Did you use an image for that? Using `QBrush` with a `QColor` is the same as using `QColor` directly. The idea was to use an image.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your post correctly. With a QBrush constructed from a one-pixel-image filled with the desired color, I actually get the result I want. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Glad I could help! I wrote the solution as an answer so you can accept it if it turned out to be correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a single color as the background (`QBrush` constructed from a `QColor`), the style engine tries to render a styled background, which in your case draws this gradient with border.

You can trick the style engine by using a `QBrush` constructed from a `QImage`, so the render engine draws *exactly* that image and nothing more. In your case, use **an image with a single pixel**, namely the color you want as the background. For this, construct a 1x1-sized `QImage` and set the color of the pixel using `fill`, then use that image as a brush:

```
// Create the image (using the default image format)
QImage img(QSize(1, 1), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);

// Set the color, here light gray:
img.fill(QColor(224, 224, 224));

// Apply the image as the background for the item:
item->setBackground(QBrush(img));
```